# Merge de dois objetos com índice NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código, que obtém dados do ***local storage*** e realiza o *merge* de novos dados, porém, ao inserir este novo objeto, o índice é preenchido automaticamente como *Not a Number* (**NaN**):

```
var local = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('x')).caracs_fisicas;
var new_data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([{'id_caracteristica': '39', 'id_detalhe': '38'}]));

var resultado = $.merge(local, new_data);
```

Logo, o resultado é o seguinte:

[image: Captura do Console]

Answer (score -2):

Para resolver esse problema, você precisa garantir que "local" e "new_data" são ambos objetos válidos antes de tentar realizar o merge. Isso pode ser feito verificando se o valor retornado por "localStorage.getItem('x')" e "JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([{'id_caracteristica': '39', 'id_detalhe': '38'}]))" são diferentes de nulo e/ou undefined antes de passá-los para o método "JSON.parse()". Além disso, você pode verificar se o objeto retornado por "JSON.parse()" é realmente um objeto válido, verificando se ele tem propriedades e métodos.

```
var localStorageData = localStorage.getItem('x');
if (localStorageData) {
    var local = JSON.parse(localStorageData);
    if (local && local.caracs_fisicas) {
        var new_data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([{'id_caracteristica': '39', 'id_detalhe': '38'}]));
        if(new_data){
            var resultado = $.merge(local.caracs_fisicas, new_data);
            console.log(resultado);
        } else {
            console.error('new_data is not valid object');
        }
    } else {
        console.error('local.caracs_fisicas is not valid object');
    }
} else {
    console.error('localStorageData is not present');
}
```

Aqui, primeiro verificamos se há dados no local storage e se o objeto retornado pelo método JSON.parse() é válido, e em seguida verificamos se o objeto new_data é válido, antes de realizar o merge. Isso garantirá que você não está tentando realizar operações em objetos nulos ou indefinidos, evitando assim erros como o "Not a Number (NaN)".